# Google's material design with Django? (w/out node.js)

Tags: django

I stumbled upon google's material design web components ("https://material.io/") and would like to implement it in my projects. The only problem is that all the documentation are written for node.js.

Is it possible to use Material Design with Django/jinja?

Note: Google's Material Design is the successor of Material Design Lite.

Answer (score 0):

- It should be straight forward, if you can use angular as your frontend
  with django.
- Start an angular project in app-name/static/app-name
- Install material design(https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) the way you would add a dependency

  npm install app --save-dev

Comment: What do you mean by "start an angular project"? This is all foreign to me, would you more tips by any chance?

Comment: willer2k unfortunately I cannot help you but you are looking for help about [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/) whereas Mihir refers to [Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/material2), which is exclusively for Angular (a JavaScript framework).